# Canonical and Alternate Tags for Mobile First Indexing

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical, rel-alternate

We have mobile & desktop websites running on different sub-domains (m. and www.). We want our mobile content to be crawled and treated as the primary site. How should I handle Canonical and Alternate tags.?

Answer (score 1):

Point your entire www site to the m site with canonical on each page.

It's also better of you can create a responsive site that works on desktop and mobile as most sites have moved away from the mobile sub domain protocol. You can do this by looking into meta viewport=1. If you can get your site to be responsive with viewport then you can 301 redirect your mobile subdomain to the www version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're asking is what you really *want* to do.

If you are *sure* you only really want to have the mobile view used for all users, and get rid of the non-mobile template altogether (which is what you seem to be asking) then just use a 301 redirect assuming it's something simple like www.example.foo to m.example.foo

However I suspect you wanted to ask about how to [add an alternate or mobile view in google search concole](https://www.google.com/search?q=add%20a%20mobile%20view%20in%20google%20search%20concole) (or just [Add a website property](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en)) without removing your previous desktop site.